# How do I separate words in notepad++, Excel or similar?

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, text-editors

Here is the data what I have got.

> Abdul Rashid a025684t@usa.nit 245 ST.CLOUD VILLAGi CT. # 101 MILPTTAS
>   CA 73634 9600280136

and the output should be like

> Abdul Rashid
>
> a025684t@usa.nit
>
> 245 ST.CLOUD VILLAGi CT. # 101

and so on.

Can anyone help me, it is not necessary that it should be done in Notepad++, it can also be in Excel.

I did try with code alignment, TextFx, however, nothing worked.

Comment: You have to let us know the general format of your data for you to get suitable answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of regex to do a replace in Notepad++

```
Search, Replace, Search Mode: Regular expression
Find what: (.*) (.*?@.*?) (.*)
Replace with: \1\r\n\2\r\n\3\r\n
```

- .* is match anything but empty, and as much as the pattern allows.
- .*? is match anything but empty, but as little as the pattern
  allows.
- (Brackets) is keep the content for use later as \1, \2, etc.
- \r\n is a new line.